# Is there a way to remove title bar in atom-editor in linux

Tags: linux, atom-editor, titlebar, cson

I am trying to remove the title bar on atom in linux. The extensions there seem to offer no help since most of them are mac-oriented. I have found an answer to this here but the code provided does not seem to affect the title-bar, only the editor

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you can remove the title bar by going to Settings>Core>Title Bar.